# How to convert month number to month name in php

Tags: php

Is there a function in php wherein you can convert the number 12 to its equivalent in a month. 
For example if the mysql database stores digits and not words for dates.
how do you convert the number 12 into the word december?

Comment: This sounds a bit rudimentary since you could quickly and easily setup an array to index 12 values, so I'm guessing you have a bigger problem that you're trying to address.  Care to elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do like:

```
echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, 12));
```

Comment: @symcbean: I did not notice that but fixed before seeing your comment. Thanks

Comment: The code will work fine, so long as the script is only ever executed in January.

Comment: @Sarfraz: `foreach (range(1,12) as $num) echo date('F', strtotime($num));` gives  `JanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuaryJanuary`

Comment: @salathe: hmm that's right, unfortunately i only gave try to digit 1, thanks for that, fixed now.

Comment: @Sarfraz: You're welcome. Aside: why this answer was accepted when it didn't do what was asked, I've no idea!

Comment: @salath: yup, the answer of St. John Johnson should be accepted still.

Answer (score 11):

Try this and look at the [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more answers:

```
date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, 12))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
strftime("%B", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12));
```

It's like date() except it will take care of localization for you, if you set a locale using [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do that directly in MySQL with

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(12, '%m')); -- December
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Or in PHP-land (as of PHP 5.3) if for some reason doing it in MySQL isn't possible: `DateTime::createFromFormat('n', $num)->format('F')`

Answer (score 1):

```
date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 1, 2000));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, 2010));
```

Where $month is your number from 1 to 12.

Read more at php functions reference:
[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)